# Python odeint error with system of ODE

Tags: python, numerical-methods, ode

I'm using a very simple system of differential equations:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odein

def Comp(state, t, u1, k1, y1, u2, k2, y2):
    X1 = state[0]
    X2 = state[1]
    S = state[2]
    dX1 = u1*(S/(k1+S))*X1
    dX2 = u2*(S/(k2+S))*X2
    dS = -(1/y1)*u1*(S/(k1+S))*X1 -(1/y2)*u2*(S/(k2+S))*X2
    return [dX1, dX2, dS]
time = np.linspace(0, 10000, 100000)
states = odeint(Comp, [0.5, 0.5, 365], time, args=(0.25, 2, 0.35, 0.25, 1, 0.7))
print(states[-1])

[  8.48291791e+01   8.73416418e+01  -7.74542370e-39]
```

with `S` and `X` being concentrations. Because of that S should never be negative, but when I solve this system with odeint `S` always become negative after some time...

Can I enforce the desired behaviour somehow?

Comment: Can you show the actual code?

Comment: The code you've posted (illegal python, btw) would be interpreted by python (if legal, that is) `S' = u S X / (k+S)`, otoh your tail placement of `X` could suggest that your intention would rather be `S' = u S /(kX+SX)`.  Could you please clarify this point to someone that doesn't know a thinkg of diffusion equations?

Comment: Sorry, I edit the question. It's the first option. Can you show me how to post code?

Comment: You can post code using the same code formatting blocks in which you've put your 2 equations, but you should read this if you'd like better responses: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)